# Docker container back up when updating the environment variable of the docker image

Tags: docker

After looking through many questions about update env in Docker container, I find out that I need to delete and recreate the docker container with the new environments but in case I want to roll back to the old environment, do I just need to delete and recreate the container again ?

Another option I'm thinking is to stop the old container, rename it, then I can run the new container and if it doesn't work, I will delete and rename the old container back to the original name. Would this option be feasible for backup purpose ?

For creating the container, I use `docker run`  with `-e` to add the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containers are meant to be disposable. Data that you need to persist between disposing of one container and launching another should be stored in a database, or if necessary a data volume.

If you're running an upgrade- changing from one container version to another- then you likely want to backup your data. For volumes that can be as simple as copying the data to another directory, while database each have their own method depending on the engine you're using.

For something like changing an environment variable it's standard to throw the container away and launch a new one with the changed value. If it doesn't work you throw it away and launch again with the old value.

You may want to read [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/), as it touches on a lot of the principles around container based development.